# Can't overlap text with SwiftUI Datepicker

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm trying to cover a datepicker with a text view since the SwiftUI datepicker isn't very customizable. This way I can control how the label looks with different colors than the datepicker.

The problem i'm running into is that the datepicker doesn't register taps when something is placed on top of it. Either in a ZStack or a .overlay.

I've tried many different workaround such as setting the .opacity to zero in front of the text

```
ZStack {
    DatePicker("Due Date", selection: $startDate, displayedComponents: .date)
        .labelsHidden()
        .cornerRadius(10)
        .allowsHitTesting(true)
    Text("hi this is text")
        .allowsHitTesting(false)

}
```

Any help?

Comment: This has got to be a bug right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take the opposite approach and flip the order of the `ZStack`, putting the `Text` behind the `DatePicker` setting the `DatePicker`'s opacity to a low value. Even cleaner is just using a `background`:

```
DatePicker("Due Date", selection: $startDate, displayedComponents: .date)
            .labelsHidden()
            .allowsHitTesting(true)
            .opacity(0.0101)
            .background(Text("Hi - this is text!"))
```

SwiftUI won't track hits on invisible elements, so the opacity can't be 0. In fact, it seems to stop registering with anything `<=` `0.1`. So, it's not *perfect*, but it looks pretty invisible to me.